# Zend link helper exists?

Tags: php, zend-framework

Some other frameworks have a link helper like `output_link('anchor', 'destination');` to replace the need to type `<a href=""></a>` into the template. Does Zend have something similar? and do I have to declare the link in the action first before I can use it in the viewer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Zend_View_Helper_Url can generate URL in view, take a look on its API doc
http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/core/Zend_View/Helper/Zend_View_Helper_Url.html

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if Zend has this, but all you would need to do is create your own `outputLink` in the [View Helper](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html) (`applications/views/helpers/`) and set it up how you want to, should be pretty trivial.

```
class Zend_View_Helper_OutputLink extends Zend_View_Helper_Abstract
{
    public function outputLink($anchor, $description)
    {
        return '<a href="' . $anchor . '">' . $description . '</a>';
    }
}
```

Just modify it how you want to. And you would call it in your view like below:

```
<span><?php $this->outputLink('test.html', 'Test Me!'); ?> </span>
```

Comment: For outputting HTML tags is better to extend `Zend_View_Helper_HtmlElement` instead `Zend_View_Helper_Abstract`. It has nice methods for handling HTML attributes.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my anchor element view helper for zend. You need to use my image element view helper or remove the part of the code that uses it in case you don't like it. Of course, you're free to modify name and whatever else you wish.

```
require_once 'Zend/View/Helper/HtmlElement.php';

class Ecoweb_View_Helper_AnchorElement extends Zend_View_Helper_HtmlElement {

    /**
     *
     * @param string $url
     * @param string $content
     * @param array|string $attribs
     * @return string 
     */
    public function anchorElement($url, $content = '', $attribs = null)
    {
        if (is_array($url)) {
            $reset = isset($url[2]) ? $url[2] : false;
            $encode = isset($url[3]) ? $url[3] : false;
            $url = $this->view->url($url[0], $url[1], $reset, $encode);
        } else {
            $url = $this->view->baseUrl($url);
        }

        if (is_array($attribs)) {
            $attribs = $this->_htmlAttribs($attribs);
        } else {
            $attribs = empty($attribs) ? '' : ' '.$attribs;
        }

        if (is_array($content) && isset($content['src'])) {
            $src = $content['src'];
            $alt = isset($content['alt']) ? $content['alt'] : null;
            $imgAttribs = isset($content['attribs']) ? $content['attribs'] : array();

            $content = $this->view->imgElement($src, $alt, $imgAttribs);
        }
        $content = empty($content) ? $url : $this->view->escape($content);

        $xhtml = '<a '
                . 'href="'.$url.'"'
                . $attribs
                . '>'
                . $content
                . '</a>';

        return $xhtml;
    }

}
```

Here's the image element view helper:

```
<?php

require_once 'Zend/View/Helper/HtmlElement.php';

class Ecoweb_View_Helper_ImgElement extends Zend_View_Helper_HtmlElement {

    /**
     *
     * @param string $src
     * @param string $alt
     * @param array|string $attribs
     * @return string 
     */
    public function imgElement($src, $alt = '', $attribs = null)
    {
        $src = $this->view->baseUrl($src);

        if (is_array($attribs)) {
            $attribs = $this->_htmlAttribs($attribs);
        } else {
            $attribs = empty($attribs) ? '' : ' '.$attribs;
        }

        $alt = $this->view->escape($alt);

        $xhtml = '<img '
                . 'src="'.$src.'" '
                . 'alt="'.$alt.'"'
                . $attribs
                . $this->getClosingBracket();

        return $xhtml;
    }

}
```

Use cases:

```
echo $this->anchor('/mycontroller/myaction');
// output: <a href="/mycontroller/myaction">/mycontroller/myaction</a>

echo $this->anchor('/mycontroller/myaction', 'My anchor content', 'rel="nofollow"');
// output: <a href="/mycontroller/myaction" rel="nofollow">My anchor content</a>

echo $this->anchor('/mycontroller/myaction', 'My anchor content', 'rel="nofollow"');
// output: <a href="http://mydomain.com/mycontroller/myaction" rel="nofollow">My anchor content</a>
// when baseUrl is http://mydomain.com

echo $this->anchor(array(array('controller' => 'mycontroller', 'action' => 'myaction'), 'myroute'), 'My anchor content', array('rel' => 'nofollow'));
// output: <a href="/mycontroller/myaction" rel="nofollow">My anchor content</a>

echo $this->anchor('/mycontroller/myaction', array('src' => '/uploads/myimag.png'));
// output: <a href="/mycontroller/myaction"><img src="/uploads/myimag.png" alt=""></a>
// when you have an html doctype

echo $this->anchor('/mycontroller/myaction', array('src' => '/uploads/myimag.png', 'alt'=>'My alt text', array('width' => '100')));
// output: <a href="/mycontroller/myaction"><img src="/uploads/myimag.png" alt="My alt text" width="100" /></a>
// when you have an xhtml doctype
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, Zend's url helper kind of thing kinda sucks. This is the only thing that pains me while developing apps in zend. In Codeigniter url helper used to come very handy. Zend has very limited resources in case of this. I had to port CI's url helper to use in my Zend Apps. And moreover, Symfony doesn't have that many helper methods like CI has and I'm not sure why.

Answer (score -1):

No, you have to make one.